# Problems with webviewbrush and Rectangle

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-8

I'm having problems hiding a webview, my application is based on a webview as I'm showing words definitions with an html format, when I need to show any settings pane or any other element over the webview I need to hide it and fill a rectangle with a webviewbrush...

The problem is that when I do it, the rectangle shows an stretched image... I've tried using different stretch settings both for the webview brush and rectangle but can't make it look exactly like the webview...

For example if I use stretch none on the webviewbrush.. it works under some resolutions, but on higher resolutions it shows the image bigger than it is...

I can't seem to find a fix for this... could anybody give me a hand?

Answer (score 0):

Try the [MSDN-Example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.appbar.opened), it works well on my project. If it doesen't work create a new clean project and try it without your additional xaml maybe you mest up some properties ;-)

XAML:

```
<Grid>
    <WebView x:Name="contentView" Source="http://www.contoso.com"/>
    <Rectangle x:Name="contentViewRect"/>
</Grid>
```

Code behind:

```
private void AppBar_Opened(object sender, object e)
{
    WebViewBrush wvb = new WebViewBrush();
    wvb.SourceName = "contentView";
    wvb.Redraw();
    contentViewRect.Fill = wvb;
    contentView.Visibility = Windows.UI.Xaml.Visibility.Collapsed;     
}

private void AppBar_Closed(object sender, object e)
{
    contentView.Visibility = Windows.UI.Xaml.Visibility.Visible;
    contentViewRect.Fill = new SolidColorBrush(Windows.UI.Colors.Transparent);
}
```

Comment: I found the solution... it was a combination of stretches and widths... this sample didn't work from scratch... I already tried it at the beggining, but thanks anyway.